# Showing that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{1/2} n^{-1} (1 - \cos(n^2 k^{-2}))=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does anyone know how to show $ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{1/2} n^{-1} (1 - \cos(n^2 k^{-2}))=\infty$? My thoughts were that you should you a series approximation of some sort, but I don't know how to get through it.

Comment: maybe you could change the upper limit of the sum to n (so that you have a lower bound). Then, note that $(n/k)^2$ is rational by definition, so it's never a multiple of $\pi$, which implies that the $1-cos((n/k)^2)>t$ for some constant t. I think it's pretty clear that this new limit is $>\log n$. Word of caution: my analysis is sloppy, and I could be way  off.

Comment: So what you are saying is that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{1/2} n^{-1} (1 - \cos(n^2 k^{-2})) >\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^{1/2} n^{-1} t(n)$, since $t$ must depend on $n$, right? How is this limit $>log(n)$?

Comment: The solution below seems correct, I said $\log n$ since $\sum^{n} k^{1/2}/n > \sum^{\sqrt n}_{k=1} (k/ \sqrt{n}) \approx 1/2 \log n$

Answer (score 2):

Define $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
c,\;\;x\in [\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{3\pi}{2}]\\
0,\;\;otherwise
\end{cases}$$
where $c\approx 0$ and $c> 0$. Then $1-\cos(x)\geq f(x)$ for $x\in [0,\dfrac{3\pi}{2}]$.

$\dfrac{n^2}{k^2}<\dfrac{\pi}{2}\Leftrightarrow k>\sqrt{\dfrac{2}{\pi}}n$

We have
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{1/2} n^{-1} (1 - \cos(n^2 k^{-2}))\geq 
\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^{1/2} n^{-1} f(n^2 k^{-2})\geq
\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}n}k^{1/2} n^{-1} f(n^2 k^{-2})\geq$$
$$\geq c\sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}n}k^{1/2} n^{-1}\approx
\dfrac{c}{n} \int _1 ^{\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}n} x^{1/2}dx \geq \bar{c}\sqrt{n}
\to \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Let
$s(n, m)
= \sum_{k=1}^{m}k^{1/2} n^{-1} (1 - \cos(n^2 k^{-2}))
$

$1 - \cos(n^2 k^{-2})
= 2\sin^2(\frac{n^2}{2k^2})
$
so
$s(n,m)
= 2\sum_{k=1}^{m}k^{1/2} n^{-1}\sin^2(\frac{n^2}{2k^2})
$.

If
$m > n$ then

$\begin{array}\\
s(n,m)
&= 2\sum_{k=1}^{m}k^{1/2} n^{-1}\sin^2(\frac{n^2}{2k^2})\\
&> 2\sum_{k=n}^{m}k^{1/2} n^{-1}\sin^2(\frac{n^2}{2k^2})\\
&> 2\sum_{k=n}^{m}k^{1/2} n^{-1}(\frac{n^2}{2k^2})^2(\frac{4}{\pi^2})\\
&> \frac{8}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=n}^{m}k^{1/2} n^{-1}\frac{n^4}{k^4}\\
&= \frac{8}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=n}^{m}\frac{n^3}{k^{7/2}}\\
&= \frac{8n^3}{\pi^2}\sum_{k=n}^{m}\frac{1}{k^{7/2}}\\
&\approx \frac{8n^3}{\pi^2}\int_{n}^{m}x^{-7/2}dx\\
&= \frac{8n^3}{\pi^2}\dfrac{x^{-5/2}}{-5/2}_{n}^{m}\\
&= \frac{8n^3}{\pi^2}\dfrac{m^{-5/2}-n^{-5/2}}{-5/2}\\
&= \frac{16n^3}{5\pi^2}(n^{-5/2}-m^{-5/2})\\
&= \frac{16n^{1/2}}{5\pi^2}(1-(m/n)^{-5/2})\\
&= \frac{16n^{1/2}}{5\pi^2}(1-(n/m)^{5/2})\\
\end{array}
$

If $m > 2n$ then
$s(n, m)
\gt \frac{16n^{1/2}}{5\pi^2}(1-(1/2)^{-5/2})
\gt \frac{8n^{1/2}}{5\pi^2}
\to \infty$
as $n \to \infty$.